# PHP APC apc.shm_size cant be set above 39

Tags: php, apache, apc

Hi I am having some problems with apc caching.  For some reason when I set the apc.shm_size to any value above 39 I am unable to load any php files.  There are no entries in the apache error logs.

My set up is as follows:

PHP 5.3.5
Apache 2.2.17

Loaded apache modules:
core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_actions mod_alias mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_default mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_vhost_alias mod_php5

Comment: Yes i do, although the unit is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a library limitation of whatever APC was compiled with for its Win32 version.  While the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-size) doesn't mention Win32, it does note that the BSD operating systems have a fairly low limit for shared memory segment size.

Having said that, APC allows you to create multiple shared memory segments using the [`apc.shm_segments`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-segments) setting to get around shared memory segment size limits.

The default is 1 segment, 32MB in size.